# Language to accompany regular expression

Tags: java, regex

My apologies if this doesn't quite make sense, hopefully it comes across ok.

I have an app that you can specify a regex in a config file that is used to match against a list of items. It then has various config options as to what to do with the captured groups, eg if the regex matches this item:

`data_20190503_120303.tsv`

with regex of

`data_(?<yyyy>\d{4})(?<MM>\d\d)(?<dd>\d\d)_(?<hh>\d\d)(?<mm>\d\d)(?<ss>\d\d)\.tsv`

Then it might have config entries of how to use the captured groups

`groupby=$yyyy$MM$dd
orderby=$yyyy$MM$dd$hh$mm$ss`

This is working quite well but then I thought I would add some features such as converting month like Jan, feb etc to 01, 02 so define it like this:

`orderby=$yyyy${convertMonth:$MMM}$dd`

Then I've added a few other functions and features. So I've started to define a language as how to assemble the captured group.

So, my question is, does something like this exist? Am I reinventing the wheel? Is there something that exists that would have a ton of features?

Comment: The only thing I'm aware of would be something like [OGNL](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Graph_Navigation_Language). That wouldn't work on regular expressions directly but if you'd collect the expressions into an object or a map (with key = group name and value = group value) you might then be able to apply further expressions to that.

Comment: Thanks. I got to "Ist eine expression lanuage" and that was the limit of my basic german :-)

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't pay attention to the text. Here's the english version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OGNL :)